# TypeError: Cannot read property 'publish' of undefined in (ReactJS)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, button, properties

I have this code in my main.js file:

```
import Link from 'gatsby-link';
import Cookies from 'universal-cookie';
import "isomorphic-fetch";
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import './style.css';
import { MuiThemeProvider, createMuiTheme } from 'material-ui/styles';
import {amber,blue,red} from 'material-ui/colors';
import AppBar from 'material-ui/AppBar';
import Toolbar from 'material-ui/Toolbar';
import Typography from 'material-ui/Typography';
import Tabs, { Tab } from 'material-ui/Tabs';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { withStyles } from 'material-ui/styles';
import Table, { TableBody, TableCell, TableHead, TableRow } from 'material-ui/Table';
import Paper from 'material-ui/Paper';
import Button from 'material-ui/Button';
//import SingleInput from 'material-ui/components/SingleInput';  

import Avatar from 'material-ui/Avatar';
import DateRangeIcon from 'material-ui-icons/DateRange';
import AssignmentIcon from 'material-ui-icons/Assignment';
import NoteIcon from 'material-ui-icons/Note';
//import 'react-fab/dist/main.scss';
import * as firebase from 'firebase'

const cookies = new Cookies();
var name = (cookies.get('name'));
var key = (cookies.get('key'));
console.log(key);
const theme = createMuiTheme ({
  palette: {
    primary: amber,
    secondary: blue
  },
  root: {
  flexGrow: 1,
  },
  bottomView:{

      width: '25%', 
      height: 50, 
      backgroundColor: '#FF9800', 
      justifyContent: 'center', 
      alignItems: 'center',
      position: 'absolute',
      right: 0
    },
});
class Base {
  constructor() {
  }
}

class Homework extends Base{


 constructor() {
      super();

    this.state = {
      topicBox: null,
      payloadBox: null
    };

    this.publish = this.publish.bind(this);
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    }
 publish(event) {
    this.setState({value: event.target.value});
  }
  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({value: event.target.value});
  }  
  async loadTest() {
    try {
      //grab courses
      const response = await fetch('https://classroom.googleapis.com/v1/courses?access_token=' + key);
      const json = await response.json();
      //coursemax vars will eventually be user defined
      var coursemax = [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2];

      if(json.courses!=null){
        for(var course =0;course<json.courses.length&&course<9;course++ ){
          //grab course info
          var coursework = await fetch('https://classroom.googleapis.com/v1/courses/' +json.courses[course].id+'/courseWork?access_token='+key);
          var coursejson = await coursework.json();
          console.log(coursejson);
          var assignment ="";
          for(var assignmentnum in coursejson.courseWork){
            if (assignmentnum<=coursemax[course]-1){
              //add in assignment
              assignment += "<p>" +coursejson.courseWork[assignmentnum].title+"</p>";
              //"Due: "+coursejson.courseWork[assignmentnum].dueDate.month+"/"+coursejson.courseWork[assignmentnum].dueDate.day
            }
          }
          //making ids to render
          document.getElementById('class'+(course+1)+'info').innerHTML = assignment;
          document.getElementById('class'+(course+1)).innerHTML = json.courses[course].name+'</b>'+':'+'<br/>';;
        }
      }
    } catch(err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  }
}
var app = new Homework();
  var config = {
    apiKey: "xxx",
    authDomain: "xxx",
    databaseURL: "xxx",
    projectId: "xxx",
    storageBucket: "xxx",
    messagingSenderId: "xxx"
  };
  firebase.initializeApp(config);
app.loadTest();

  function publish() {
    console.log( this.state.topicBox, this.state.payloadBox );
  const itemsRef = firebase.database().ref('Users');
  const item = {
    title: this.state.topicBox,
    user: this.state.payloadBox
  }
  itemsRef.push(item).set("name");
  this.setState({
    topicBox: '',
    payloadBox: ''
  });

  }

const LoginPage = () =>
<MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <div>
        <AppBar position="static" id='title'>
          <Toolbar>
            <Typography type="title" color='inherit'>
              MVHS Homework App
            </Typography>
            <div id='avatar' color='inherit'><Avatar>{name[0]}</Avatar></div>
          </Toolbar>
        </AppBar>
        <Paper id='calendar'>
          <Table>
            <TableHead>
              <TableRow>
                <TableCell><p id = "class1"></p></TableCell>
                <TableCell><p id = "class1info"></p></TableCell>
              </TableRow>
              <TableRow>
                <TableCell><p id = "class2"></p></TableCell>
                <TableCell><p id = "class2info"></p></TableCell>
              </TableRow>
              <TableRow>
                <TableCell><p id = "class3"></p></TableCell>
                <TableCell><p id = "class3info"></p></TableCell>
              </TableRow>
              <TableRow>
                <TableCell><p id = "class4"></p></TableCell>
                <TableCell><p id = "class4info"></p></TableCell>
              </TableRow>
              <TableRow>
                <TableCell><p id = "class5"></p></TableCell>
                <TableCell><p id = "class5info"></p></TableCell>
              </TableRow>
              <TableRow>
                <TableCell><p id = "class6"></p></TableCell>
                <TableCell><p id = "class6info"></p></TableCell>
              </TableRow>
              <TableRow>
                <TableCell><p id = "class7"></p></TableCell>
                <TableCell><p id = "class7info"></p></TableCell>
              </TableRow>
            </TableHead>
          </Table>
        </Paper>
      <form>

      <input 
        type="text" 
        name="topicBox" 
        placeholder="Name" 
        //value={ this.state.topicBox }
        //onChange={ this.handleChange } 
      />
      <input 
        type="text" 
        name="payloadBox" 
        placeholder="Details"
        //value={ this.state.payloadBox } 
        //onChange={ this.handleChange } 
      />
      </form>
      <Button variant="raised" color="secondary" style = {theme.bottomView} onClick={ this.publish }>
        Add
      </Button>
      </div>

    </MuiThemeProvider>



export default LoginPage
```

I have this Error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'publish' of undefined

On this line:

```
<Button variant="raised" color="secondary" style = {theme.bottomView}
onClick={ this.publish }>
```

How can I fix this and what is wrong? Is there some code I'm missing?

***EDIT***: Please tell me if you need any more code or info.

***EDIT/MORE DETAILS***: I want to click on a button and run the publish function.

Comment: It is better if you update the full code. Not able to get what you are trying to do

Comment: ok one second...

Comment: I added the full code everyone @aravind_reddy

Answer (score 0):

first, your codes too hard to review.

second, you have a `try` without `catch`

third, class properties like function or object dont need to declare with `const` i think it is your main problem.

**Edit**: i just review your full code you resend. this.publish is your class function of class `Homework`, LoginPage declare in file context. so this.publish mean a function declare in your module named publish . -> undefined

> Note: to auto binding a function with class, just use arrow function .

```
publish = (event) => {
    this.setState({value: event.target.value});
  }
```

Comment: So remove the declaration in the const?

Comment: Juat to clarify. Yoou say remove 'this.publish = this.publish.bind(this);'

Comment: look my edited answer, the firstime you send a wrong and not full codes

Comment: ... finally, i saw 2 function publish, use app.publish if your want to point to function in class or just call publish if you want to point function outside.

Comment: where do I use app.publish? I am very new.

Comment: I see what your saying the issue is but I don't know how to fix the code. PLEASE HELP/ @Wing

Comment: @JimHall just simple: ```onClick={app.publish}``` or ```onClick={publish}```  

i dont know the mean of function publish outside the Homework class but it is a wrong code.